# What does it mean: Visa processing Times" you need to "Select the location you are making your application from"

Tags: visas

I feel dumb asking about this, but gun shy with the visa process now.

1. under  the UK Gov site to see "Visa processing Times" you need to
   "Select the location you are making your application from"
2. The way I read it, that it means either my town, my state or my
   country.
3. However, in drop down menu it offers limited cities and countries
   together.

   I. It has a few major cities like Chicago, NY and DC, but nothing near me.

   II. It does have a option for DHS-Vac, USA, which googled is “Application 
   Support Centers"
4. What exactly does that mean?
5. Since it seems to have limited options, I don't really understand
   exactly what it means "Select the location you are making your
   application from".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the location where you are submitting your visa application.

If you are submitting it in the USA, you should choose New York as that is where you will submit your application. See the [instructions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).

Comment: Thank you. Very useful and thank you for taking the time to help me. I am happy to have found this site.

Comment: \*boggle\* They write "location you are applying from" when they mean "location you are applying _to_". Actually, the standard of English from VFS seems to be pretty poor. We keep getting questions about that letter saying "your visa application has been concluded" that seems to be supposed to say "processing of your visa application has been concluded".

Comment: @DavidRicherby The standard of everything from VFS seems to be pretty poor. I'm continually amazed that people actually get visas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the wording is correct, "location you are applying from". An application for a visa to the UK is being done _from_ (via) New York.

Comment: @mkennedy If I am sitting at home, filling in a web form to apply for a visa (which the asker is), I am "applying" and my "location" is my home. So the "location I am applying from" is wherever my home is. As you say, I may be applying _via_ New York, but I'm not applying _from_ New York unless that is where I am. It should say something like "Select the visa office you are applying to."